# How to make sure the text of a list item is only one line?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a list of items that have a text title. What I would like to do is if the text goes past one line to cut off the three characters before and have it say ... instead.

This is how I call the helper function that renders the title:

```
<ListItem
  title={this.renderTitle(todoItem.text)}
  titleStyle={{ color: '#FCEFEF', fontSize: 16 }}
/>
```

And this is my helper function:

```
renderTitle(text) {
    if (text.length > 55) {
      const badCharacters = text.length - 54;
      let goodText = text.substring(0, text.length - badCharacters);
      goodText += '...';
      return goodText; //text up until character 51, then 52,53,54 is ...
    }
    return text;
  }
```

I am unsure how to check for this though, I tried calculating the number of characters but this doesn't work. It seems that it isn't a number of characters that it is limited to but the width of them, for example, if the string is all 'f' it can have more characters on one line than if they are all 'a'.

Comment: [css ellipsis](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment was correct, solution is this:

```
<ListItem
  title={
    <Text style={{ color: '#FCEFEF', fontSize: 16 }} ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1}>
        {todoItem.text}
    </Text>
}
```